# QML show window on specified screen

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have hybrid QML/QWidget application and I want to show QML window on the specified screen. Here's the code defining a screen number

```
int activeScreenIndex = QApplication::desktop()->screenNumber(QApplication::activeWindow());
```

Now I want to show QML component `Window` on the screen I've defined this way. Another problem is that I create QML windows unisng `Instantiator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Window::screen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#screen-prop) was introduced in Qt 5.9.

```
Window {
    screen: Qt.application.screens[activeScreenIndex]
}
```

Comment: I've installed Qt 5.9 with MinGW 5.3.0, but I'm gettings `invalid property name "screen"` error and `screen` is underlined. `Component not ready` printed when I start the application. What's wrong?

Comment: Documentation says that `import QtQuick.Window 2.2` but `import QtQuick.Window 2.3` fixed this problem